# AWK: replace and write a column value in the input file

Tags: awk

I am trying to replace the $3 column values of the input file if $3 is > 100. I tried:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {if($3 > 100) $3=$3/100;print}' test.stat
```

This outputs the correct changes to the stdout, but I need the change to be written to the input file (`test.stat`) such that the values of the remaining fields/records remain unchanged. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Awk isn't designed to edit things in-place.  It's designed to process data and write it to stdout (or another file).  You can do something like this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {if($3 > 100) $3=$3/100;print}' test.stat > test.stat.new \
    && mv test.stat test.stat.old && mv test.stat.new test.stat
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of AWK's restriction

Comment: but, it does not preserve the formatting, i.e., my input fields are separated by tabs but, the edited record has the fields separated by space. Also, how to limit the float to 2 d.p before printing. thanks

Comment: where will the redirection be placed if I also have an END clause that prints a counter that was initialized in the BEGIN? Thanks.

Comment: It will go to the same place - stdout.

Comment: sorry, to clarify my question, I tried the following and getting errors: awk 'BEGIN{$counter=0} {if($3 > 100) $3=$3/100;print else $counter++;}END{print $counter}' test.stat > ...

Comment: awk isn't perl or php.  `$aVariable` references the "aVariable"th field in the current line of input.  Just `counter` will do.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {if($3 > 100) $3=$3/100;print}' test.stat > /tmp/tmp.stat && mv /tmp/tmp.stat test.stat
```

this should work

Comment: Thanks. but, it does not preserve the formatting, i.e., my input fields are separated by tabs but, the edited record has the fields separated by space. Also, how to limit the float to 2 d.p before printing. thanks

Comment: @shuvo-shams - output separator is space by default, can be changed via OFS, e. g. `awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS="\t"} { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know `awk` doesn't have in-place editing as `sed` does (via the `-i` switch).

The easy solution, of course, is to use a temp file and overwrite the original file afterwards. This is the solution recommended even in [comp.lang.awk](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.awk/msg/c91780b735f1b6be).

The harder solution is to save the changes to an `awk` array and add an `END` block that dumps the contents of the array to the original file.

Answer (score 2):

To make your command more awk-like:

```
awk -F '\t' '$3 > 100 {$3 = $3/100} {print}' test.stat
```

To overwrite the file, you need to write to a temp file

```
f=$(mktemp)
cp test.stat test.stat.bak$(date +%s)  ;# if you want a backup copy
awk '...' test.stat > "$f" && mv "$f" test.stat
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Awk, it has an `-i inplace` option which works similarly to the (nonstandard but common) `-i` option of `sed`. In other words, it will write the changes back to the original file (probably using a temporary file behind the scenes).

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}
  {if($3 > 100) $3=$3/100;print}' test.stat
```

Tangentially, you might want to preserve the tabs on output, and simplify the syntax slightly.

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
  ($3 > 100) { $3=$3/100 } 1' test.stat
```

where `OFS=FS="\t"` sets both the input and the output field separators to a tab, and we use the common `1` idiom to print all input lines.

If you don't have GNU Awk, you will probably get something like

```
awk: unknown option -i ignored
```

and if you want to check which Awk you have, `awk --version` should print something like

```
GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2020 Free Software Foundation.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

Just to spell this out, there are multiple common versions of Awk. Brian Kernighan's "new Awk" (which was "new" in 1993 and is a direct descendant of the original Bell Labs Awk) is sometimes called `nawk`, and there is a version called "Mike's Awk" which is often available as `mawk`. GNU Awk is sometimes installed as `gawk`, or from a package with that name. There are [multiple other implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations), including of course a separate one for Busybox.

On Debian-like platforms, [`update-alternatives`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/update-alternatives.1.html) will let you select which Awk version from the installed ones you want to use when you type just `awk`.

Of course, the common and standard portable solution is to write the results to a new file and then move it on top of the original, as already suggested in multiple answers.