# Using awk to find and replace string in files found with find

Tags: regex, linux, bash, command-line, awk

I'm using find to grab a bunch of files in a directory, and then awk to try and find/replace a string in them.  However, awk is just printing the entire contents of the files to stdout instead of overwriting the files.  I'm a bit confused as to what syntax I should use here to accomplish my goal.

My command so far is:

```
find -iname '*_input.xml' -exec awk -P '/"prop_name" : "ID",/ , /}/ {print sub(/SKU/,"SKU+ProductId")} 1' {} +
```

THis is replacing the string `SKU` with `SKU+ProductId` but not overwriting the file.

Any one have any ideas as to what Im missing?

Cheers!

**Update:**
Example Content:

```
          },
      "prop_name" : "ID",
      "rule" : "SKU"
   },
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how to fit it into the `-exec` of the find command, but this explains why it isn't working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705940

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk writes to standard output, so you will need to redirect standard output. You can do that with `find` by executing an inner shell command:

```
find -iname '*_input.xml' \
     -exec sh -c 'for file; do
       ./awk_script "$file" > "$file.tmp" && mv "$file.tmp" "$file"
      done' _ {} +
```

I would move the awk command to its own file to avoid problems with quoting. You may also want to consider saving the task of overwriting the original files until you've checked the results.

You could create an awk file like this, I believe. Don't forget to `chmod +x` it.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/"prop_name" : "ID",/ , /}/ {
    print sub(/SKU/,"SKU+ProductId")
} 1
```

Comment: so the awk_script will need to be in the same directory as the files being found , and should be a .sh correct?

Comment: The awk script would have to be in a known directory. Its extension doesn't matter, but you could put `#!/usr/bin/awk -Pf` in the shebang.

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors when I try to execute this.  Could you edit your answer to show the contents of the awk file?  I'm editing the question to give some example content.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick using awk!  there are some 0's and 1's at the start of the lines of the file it replaced, but I can work that out.

Comment: Too complicated... Excel FTW.

Comment: How would you find files with excel?

Answer (score 2):

GNU sed has a `-i` for in place editing that makes this a lot easier:

```
find -iname '*_input.xml' \
  -exec sed -i '/"prop_name" : "ID",/ , /}/ s/SKU/SKU+ProductId/' {} +
```

Comment: ah, this definitely works, but the multiline option apparently isn't supported by sed.  Minus the `s` though, it did work which tells me it must be enforced by default.  Not sure if I should accept though since this was about awk, but def +1

Comment: [ed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) gets no love. It's POSIX compliant, actually designed to edit files, and portable. But ever since GNU decided to put the `-i` flag and make `sed` non-portable not only did everyone forget poor `ed`, but everyone forgot how to use it, too. #wahmbulance

Comment: @kojiro Wouldn't `ed` require embedding `sh` and such uglyness?

Comment: @thatotherguy It probably would require some kind of ugliness. But biiteotb, etc, etc.

Comment: @thatotherguy do sed regexs not allow for matches like [^"]+ or .*?" across mulitple lines?  when I try to go a little further with this stuff like that breaks it

Comment: @Rooster Yes and no. Sed applies the regex to its so-called pattern space, which by default is populated by the current line. There are commands to read further lines into the pattern space to do matching across them. You might find it easier [to use perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742526/how-to-search-and-replace-across-multiple-lines-with-perl).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a new-ish version of GNU awk (4.?) with the `-i infile` option and get rid of the `print`.

Comment: i'll try it out when I have some time to update the pkgs