# Merging of 2 factors in R with large no. of levels

Tags: r

I have a plain text format file `data_table_complete` of size of 13 GB with over 100 columns in which 1 there is a column related to `color`.

When I used the command `levels(data_table_complete$color)`, there were **544 levels**.

On primary search I found 1 level named as `"OTHERS"`, containing some 4000 odd items and another one as `"OTHETRS"`, containing some 600 odd items, which is possibly the spelling mistake of the former one.

So I thought to merge them as `"OTHERS"` but I found that there was possible data loss.

Can anyone guide me how to accomplish this task?

Comment: Please see [how to post a minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I suspect that you are not using the best tool here: for such a big file, I would go with `awk` rather than with `R`. See in particular if are able to adapt this to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705940/awk-replace-and-write-a-column-value-in-the-input-file

Comment: Hi Jealie I could have used awk or some better tools but as it's being asked by client to accomplish this task I am bound to do it his way.Thanks @hrbrmstr for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets say this is your data frame

```
df <- data.frame(color = factor(c(rep("red",4), rep("OTHERS", 4),rep("blue", 5), rep("OTHETRS",5))))
table(df$color)
#blue  OTHERS OTHETRS     red 
#   5       4       5       4
```

You can simply do

```
df$color <- factor(ifelse(df$color == "OTHERS" | df$color == "OTHETRS", "OTHETRS", as.character(df$color)))
table(df$color)
#blue OTHETRS     red 
#   5       9       4
```

Comment: Later I accomplished the task on **Java** using replace function